# MIDlet-1. Error in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midlet

I have two errors in NetBeans:

**Application descriptor does not declare any MIDlet. Direct execution is not allowed.
The manifest or the application descriptor MUST contain the attribute: MIDlet-1**

The files rights - 775.
Here is my MANIFEST:

```
MIDlet-1: Skeleton, /icons/Skeleton_icon.png, SkeletonMIDlet
MIDlet-Name: Skeleton
MIDlet-Description: Skeleton Example MIDlet
MIDlet-Vendor: Stalefish Labs
MIDlet-Version: 1.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add the MIDlet class to your application. Right click the application in the netbeans and choose **Properties** and then select the **Application Descriptor**. Then add the MIDlet class in **MIDlets** tab.

Comment: I added MIDlets class in netbeans bun now I have other error: wrong class ELF: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

Comment: May be this [discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/421574/JBoss/libdmcl-so-wrong-ELF-class) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to miss **application descriptor** file - [jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28file_format%29). It's not the same as manifest.

Check Netbeans documentation about it

Answer (score -1):

Find at your NetBeans project dir nbproject, edit project.properties file and remove manifest.is.liblet= tag save and compile again and no more error.